# Cronjob for service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, deployment, yaml

I need your help in understanding how to create a Kubernetes cronjob that will use curl using service nginx-server-service to get /customdir/index.html is there any way to do that?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-server
  labels:
    tier: application
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-server
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: index-html
        emptyDir: {}
      initContainers:
      - name: setup
        image: alpine:3.8
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - echo kubernetes works > /task-dir/index.html
        volumeMounts:
        - name: index-html
          mountPath: "/task-dir"
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:mainline
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: index-html
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/customdir
---
# next, a service is required to handle traffic to the pods created by the deployment

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-server-service
  labels:
    tier: networking
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30001
  selector:
    app: nginx-server
  type: ClusterIP
```

I will very much appreciate any help in digging into taht

I'm working on solution so may i ask you if it will work :

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: curljob
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      name: curljob
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
        spec:
          containers:
          - command:
            - curl
            - http://myapp-service:30001/customdir
            image: curlimages/curl
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: curljobt
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
  schedule: '*/1 * * * *'
```

i edited a bit but not sure why its not working :( begging for help

Comment: have you looked at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/?

Comment: yeah, but it was lacking of methods how to do that. Thanks btw!

Comment: try with the updated code and let me know if it fails and we can try to look further for issues if any.

Comment: no, it's failing on some step... :(

Comment: please be specific with errors. what step it is failing ?

Comment: the issue was with ClusterIP  as H.R. Emon stated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all you you are using a `ClusterIP` service type as a service. so you can't provide `NodePort` here.

then when you are trying to access a pod with service you need to call with a dns name that maintain a template.

The template is like `my_Service_Name.my_Namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example` , but you can skip the `cluster-domain.example` part. Only `Service_Name.Namespace.svc` will work fine.

so here you need to `curl` `http://nginx-server-service.default.svc/customdir/index.html`  this address.

here i have given the whole yaml that worked for me;

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-server
  labels:
    tier: application
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-server
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: index-html
        emptyDir: {}
      initContainers:
      - name: setup
        image: alpine:3.8
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - echo kubernetes works > /task-dir/index.html
        volumeMounts:
        - name: index-html
          mountPath: "/task-dir"
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:mainline
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: index-html
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/customdir
---
# next, a service is required to handle traffic to the pods created by the deployment

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-server-service
  labels:
    tier: networking
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx-server
  type: ClusterIP

---
```

here is the updated cronjob

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: curljob
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      name: curljob
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
        spec:
          containers:
          - command:
            - curl
            - http://nginx-server-service.default.svc/customdir/index.html
            image: curlimages/curl
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            name: curljobt
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
  schedule: '*/1 * * * *'
```

Comment: thank you so much! now i see where i made a mistake

Comment: one more question if i would like to change node port, to a custom one,     nodePort: 30001 - can i do that with your provided solution?

Comment: @Kwaker  yes it's possbile but in this case you need to use the url like  `<node_ip>::30007/customdir/index.html`. but a developer will really love to avoid connect with pod via `nodeIp` address. it's highly recommended that you don't use nodePort in production cluster. lets explain why i am saying that incase with `nodeport` service you need to know the exact `nodeIp` if you want to connect with the pod via `nodeport`. but it will be change if somehow your pod is restarting and it's started in new node then the ip will be changed and you can't connect with old `nodeip`.

Comment: thats why it's better you avoid nodeport. you can find in doc also that they are saying to avoid nodeport service in production cluster.